# Is an integrally closed domain of Krull dimension at most $2$ a Krull domain?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $D$ be an integrally closed domain of Krull dimension at most $2$.
Is $D$ a Krull domain?

Comment: The Wikipedia article suggests that there may be non-Noetherian counterexamples.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Of course they are not noetherian as long as a noetherian integrally closed domain is Krull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, every valuation ring of rank two is a counterexample since Krull domains are completely integrally closed, and valuation rings are completely integrally closed iff have rank at most one.

A non-discrete valuation ring of rank one is also not a Krull domain.

Comment: I found a comment cited in Matsumara book's (Commutative ring theory, 1986) p. 264 that if the dimension of $D$ is at most two then $D'$ is Noetherian.

Comment: @T.Ali And what has this to do with the question?

Comment: Because I found many examples of domain $D$ integrally closed with dimension at most 2 but not Noetherian.  $D'$ is Noetherian and $D'=D$ !!!!!

Comment: @T.Ali If you start with an integrally closed domain of dimension at most two which is not noetherian, then how could you get a noetherian domain? (Note that in the theorem you mentioned, which is on page 265, the ring $A$ is supposed noetherian, and only then $\dim A\le 2\implies A'$ noetherian.)

Comment: In theorem cited above $D$ is an integral domain which not necessarily Noetherian

Comment: See image added in the question above.

Comment: @T.Ali You missed the noetherian condition. (Btw, the section in Matsumura's book is entitled **Integral closure of a Noetherian integral domain**.)

Comment: @T.Ali In the second comment you said: "*I found many examples of domains $D$ integrally closed with dimension at most 2 but not Noetherian.* As you can see in my answer I've also found a few.

Comment: Yes, you are right. think you.